# Can ReadText be used to grab everything after a keyword?

Tags: r, vector, text, import

I'll freely admit, I'm very new to R so I might be barking up the entirely wrong tree with how to use this:

I've got text files that are just collecting output from a program over the course of a day, one day per file. Sometimes but not always, the programs throws errors. What I'm trying to work out is an R script that will import a specific part of that text file into a vector so I can play about with the listed errors. In this case, the lines of text after [ERROR]. So if I've got:

```
Normal Stuff
[ERROR] Bad Error
Normal Stuff
Normal Stuff
[ERROR] Minor Error
Normal Stuff
```

I'd end up with the vector

`Bad Error, Minor Error`

However, while I've been going through tutorials, being this surgical in data importing is something I've little experience at as I'm mostly used to importing much more precisely formatted tables. Can Readtext (Or another package) be made to do something like this or is an area where importing the entire file and searching/carving it up with string manipulation be easier?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl6)**

```
raku -ne '.put if .grep(m:i/ Error /);'    <  ~/R_Console.txt  > tmp.txt
raku -ne '.put if .grep(m:i/ Warning /);'  <  ~/R_Console.txt  > tmp.txt
raku -ne '.put if .grep(m:i/ Error | Warning /);' <  ~/R_Console.txt  > tmp.txt
```

You might want to consider implementing command line skills to munge text, and keep using R for what R does best--number-crunching and statistical analysis.

Many SO posters will tell you to learn bash, sed, awk, or perl(5), but I feel you should consider trying Raku (the new name of Perl6), a project initially conceived way back in year 2000. You can use any one of the three one-liners above to return 1. Errors, 2. Warnings, 3. Errors or Warnings.

Here are some pointers on the one-liners. The `-ne` command line flags tell Raku to take in input line-by-line. Perl-family languages understand the concept of a 'topic_variable' known as `$_` , and calling `.say` is simply an abbreviation for `$_.say` (i.e. "say the current topic"). The " `:i` " adverb makes `.grep` case-insensitive. You can delete the " `> tmp.txt` " redirection so that output prints to the Terminal (or iTerm) console. Finally, `.say` is used to produce output that is somewhat abbreviated (useful for checking code); `.say` can be replaced with `.put` which returns verbatum output.

HTH.

https://raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can read the text line by line with the help of `readLines` and use `grep` to return the lines which have `'Error'` in it. Let's assume your file is called `'temp.txt'`, you can do :

```
grep('Error', readLines('temp.txt'), value = TRUE)
#[1] "[ERROR] Bad Error"   "[ERROR] Minor Error"
```

If you want to remove the initial `'ERROR'` part you can use `sub` to get :

```
sub('[ERROR] ', '', grep('Error', readLines('temp.txt'), value = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "Bad Error"   "Minor Error"
```